# Authorization filter in Azure App service redirect to default domain rather than custom domain

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, authorization, azure-custom-domain

I have Azure app service which built in .NET 6 core. That app service has custom domain which  is accessible for all. But default domain not accessible for all and it threw `403 forbidden` error.

Now my issue is when I use **Authorize** filter on some controller methods then application redirected me to its default domain like https://app-xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Home/Login so it throws `Error 403 - Forbidden` exception. It should redirect me its custom domain https://dev.xxxxx.com/Home/Login.

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Dashboard()
 {}
```

How can I tell app to redirect to its custom domain? Can someone help me regarding this? I am working in .NET 6 core c#.